# Removing "nan" values from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that has certain rows filled exclusively with "nan", i.e.:

```
 print(ar2[1560])
[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
```

What I need is to get rid of all such lines from this numpy array, without messing up with the order of my elements, i.e. maintain the sorting. I have tried the following:

```
ar3=ar2[:,~np.all(np.isnan(ar2))]
```

but this will only replace my "nan" with "False".

I have also tried the following as well:

```
ar3 = ar2[~np.isnan(ar2)]
```

but it converts my 2d numpyarray to a 1d numpyarray.

I am aware that a solution would be to convert my numpy array to a data frame, then drop the "nan" values and then convert it back to a numpy array, but I would like to know if there is a more direct approach, exclusively within the numpy package (and other than making a huge "for" loop and iterating over everything). Thank you.

Comment: Does that mean you seek to `delete` those rows? If yes, there is a `numpy.delete` function you can use together with a `mask`.

Comment: Isn't your array 1-D anyway? It certainly looks like this as `ar3 = ar2[~np.isnan(ar2)]` is doing the correct thing

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind, found it:

```
ar3=ar2[~np.isnan(ar2).any(axis=1)]
```

Thanks anyway