# Removing nan entries from a 2-D Numpy array without for loops

Tags: python, numpy

How would I go about removing all arrays that include nan in them from a 2 dimensional Numpy Array? I want to remove the entire array that they are in. I am using Numpy arrays.

x = [[1400, 1500, 1600, nan, nan, nan ,1700],[1400, 1500, 1600, 1800, 1900, 2000 ,1700],[1400, 1500, 1600, nan, nan, nan ,1700]]

my result for x would be x = [[400, 1500, 1600, 1800, 1900, 2000 ,1700]]

My main issue as of now is that I am trying to avoid using for loops due to the length of my actual data set

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing "nan" values from a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138318/removing-nan-values-from-a-numpy-array)

Comment: You want to remove all rows with `nan` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `x = x[~np.isnan(x).any(axis=1)]` 
Ref: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/numpy/python-numpy-exercise-91.php